# I want to convert .htaccess file to web.config

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I want to convert `.htaccess` file to `web.config` .

Here is the code

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{Request_Filename} !-d
RewriteCond %{Request_Filenam}e !-f

RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9A-Za-z_\-~',]+) page_details.html?category_page_title=$1 [NC]
```

Can anybody help me to convert this .htaccess file to web.config file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice if you had made an attempt at this even just a wee bit. We respect effort greatly here, even if it's wrong or misguided. With even the briefest scan of the [IIS UrlRewrite](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/734/url-rewrite-module/) docs you would see this link: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/470/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules/, or maybe by clicking the help button in the IIS UrlRewrite feature RHS Action Panel. Even if the import didn't work properly, we'd be more than welcome to help fix that because now we have something to work with. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding conversion of whole  `.htaccess` file, see this manual: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

It is pretty comprehensive and explains how to convert the rules.

---

If you want just rewrite rules converted, read this article:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/470/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules/

This is a more step-by-step gui kind of guide, but in your case it should probably be enough.

---

In any case, the rules you listed will probably end up with this (portion of) `web.config`:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="page details" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^/pages/([0-9A-Za-z_\-~',]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>

                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/page_details.html?category_page_title={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```