# IIS7 - convert .htaccess to web.config

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config, url-rewriting

how to convert .htaccess to web.config.

I just come to know that I need to use web.config instead of htaccess. Please find my htaccess below

```
RedirectMatch 403 (?i).*\.log$
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+not_imported_.*\.txt
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+(soap|cache|xtemplate|data|examples|include|log4php|metadata|modules)/+.*\.(php|tpl)
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+emailmandelivery\.php
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+cache/+upload
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+cache/+diagnostic
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+files\.md5$


php_value auto_prepend_file D:\wamp\www\Sugarcrm\php-core-proxy.php
```

how i can convert it into web.config ?

Comment: @Nimit Dudani i think you have solve it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688714/htaccess-is-not-working-on-iis can you heplp me regarding it

Comment: check this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647807/i-want-to-convert-htaccess-file-to-web-config